# Joining 2 Select Queries (one query including an aggregate function) from two different tables

Tags: sql, left-join, aggregate-functions, databricks

I am trying to left join the two queries below (mock data for reference purposes).

```
SELECT
    marker_number AS ISN,
    IF(shelf_life_code = 'A', 1, 0) AS Store_Repaired,
    SUBSTRING(marker_number, 5, 9) AS item_number_id,
    IF(action_code = '1',1,0) AS Transferred_Main_Store,
    CAST(RIK AS INTEGER) AS Store_Days,
    process_date
FROM
    store_one.actions_table 
WHERE 
    action_ph_code = 'C8'
    AND tricche_ballak_code = 'NA'

SELECT 
    item_number_id,
    AVG(main_store_rpr_days)AS MainStore_Days,
FROM
    mstr_actions_table
GROUP BY 
    item_number_id
```

My initial approach, which doesn't work, is the following :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         marker_number AS ISN,
         IF (shelf_life_code = 'A', 1, 0) AS Store_Repaired,
         SUBSTRING(marker_number, 5, 9) AS item_number_id,
         IF (action_code = '1',1,0) AS Transferred_Main_Store,
         CAST(RIK AS INTEGER) AS Store_Days,
         process_date
     FROM
         store_one.actions_table 
     WHERE 
         action_ph_code = 'C8'
         AND tricche_ballak_code = 'NA') A
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         item_number_id,
         AVG(main_store_rpr_days)AS MainStore_Days,
     FROM
         mstr_actions_table
     GROUP BY 
         item_number_id) B ON A.item_number_id = B.item_number_id
```

Any pointer would is highly appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? I notice in subquery A you're doing string manipulation, but that same manipulation isn't present in sub-query B for `item_number_id`, is that expected? Also, a sample of the data from `actions_table` and `mst_actions_table` would be helpful.

Comment: What does "which doesn't work" mean? Are you getting a syntax error? If so, which? Are you getting incorrect results? If so, in which regard? If the separate queries work, then the combined one should work, too. It looks okay to me.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I forgot to mention that I am doing this in Databricks; queries work separately. When trying to execute together I receive the following error:
Error running query: [42000] [Simba][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: no viable alternative at input 'WITH A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    With A as(SELECT
    marker_number AS ISN,
    IF(shelf_life_code = 'A', 1, 0) AS Store_Repaired,
    SUBSTRING(marker_number, 5, 9) AS item_number_id,
    IF(action_code = '1',1,0) AS Transferred_Main_Store,
    CAST(RIK AS INTEGER) AS Store_Days,
    process_date
FROM
    store_one.actions_table 
WHERE 
    action_ph_code = 'C8'
    AND tricche_ballak_code = 'NA'),
B as(
SELECT 
    item_number_id,
    AVG(main_store_rpr_days)AS MainStore_Days,
FROM
    mstr_actions_table
GROUP BY 
    item_number_id
)
select A.*,B.MainStore_Days from A left join B on A.item_number_id=cast(B.item_number_id as varchar(10))
```

This could be the simplest solution.